# Django model extending Default User model (one-to-one field), how to create reg form for all combined model fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.10.*. This is my user profile model:

```
class student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=21, null=True, blank=True, choices=in_states.STATE_CHOICES)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=21, null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    educational_role = models.CharField(max_length=39, choices=EDUCATIONAL_ROLE)
    institute = models.ForeignKey(educational_institute, null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=LANGUAGES)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        student.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

When I created form class for student and use that to create a View class extending FormView class in my Views passing the `form` context to HTML template like this:

**forms.py :**

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = student
        fields = ['user', 'state', 'city', 'educational_role', 'institute', 'language']
```

**views.py :**

```
class Register(FormView):
    template_name = 'searcher/register.html'
    form_class = RegistrationForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Register, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['applink'] = applink
        context['forumlink'] = forumlink
        return context
```

So how do I need to modify this so that the registration form asks for `username`, `firstname`, `email` of `User` model and also the fields added by `student` model and having option for creating a new `educational_institute` if it doesn't exist already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. Would look like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Student(User):
    state = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

This way all Django features like `ModelForm` or `UpdateView` should function without any additional fiddling. In behind, Django will just create exactly the same `OneToOneField` for you.

And if all of your users are students you could also [replace the auth user model entirely](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).

If you don't want to do any of those, you will need to add additional fields into your form, specify them if you form `Meta`, take care of setting their default values (in `__init__` in example), [cleaning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) these fields and saving the model behind `OneToOneField` all by yourself.

Comment: yes i get your point, however for Auth purposes, I found out that it is much better to directly extend `AbstractUser` class rather than `User`: `class Student(AbstractUser):` . What do you say?

Comment: The only tiny difference between these two options would be that if you inherit from ```AbstractUser``` your user model will not be swappable anymore: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L367 It won't hurt, but also you will probably never want to swap it. However, just in case Django guys change something in future I would still prefer to inherit exactly from the ```User```.

Comment: In case I extend from the `User` class, can you give a complete guide about how to create a userchangeform, usercreationform, registration view (which includes all the additional fields of MyUser too'. And what to put in the `admin.py` page?